# Updating from/to plotBands values on input from a slider

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to update my Highcharts plotBands dynamically with sliders on the page. I want both `to` and `from` to be attached to slider values and dynamically updated on the canvas as the user drags the sliders. Is that possible?

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<!-- <input id="range" type="range" /> -->



<div id="slider">
    <input class="bar" type="range" id="range-input" min="1" max="25" value="1"/>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <output id="range-value">1</output>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 var rangeInput = document.getElementById("range-input")
 var rangeValue = document.getElementById("range-value")

 rangeInput.oninput = rangeOutput
 
 function rangeOutput() {
   rangeValue.innerText = rangeInput.value
 }
 
 let bla = rangeInput.value;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        marginTop: 5
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Flats sold per month'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
plotBands: [{
                from: bla,
                to: 5,
                color: 'yellow'
            }],
        title: {
            text: 'Flats'
        }
        
    },

    series: [{
        data: [1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 9, 6, 7, 3, 5, 4, 3]
    }]
});
```

Where I get stuck is updating the chart in real time. I can see there are methods to do that if I want to update my data, but I'm not sure how to do that for plotBands.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [chart.update](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/highcharts/chart-update).
First, we set your chart as `chart`.

```js
const chart = Highcharts.chart(/** **/);
```

And, now we use `chart.update` in `rangeOutput` function.

```js
chart.update({
  yAxis: {
    plotBands: [
      {
        from: rangeInput.value,
        to: 5,
        color: "yellow",
      },
    ],
    title: {
      text: "Flats",
    },
  },
});
```

Here is a [CodePen of the final code](https://codepen.io/logicstick/pen/YzBKvMM).